# Assign value of one iterator into another iterator C++

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, iterator

Say I have an iterator `it` which is pointing to some element of `map`.
Also I have another iterator `it1` , and I want to do something like this

```
it1 = it + 1;
```

How can we achieve this in C++ as above statement gives error in C++.

Comment: Bidirectional iterators don't support `operator+`. `std::next` would do that.

Comment: @chris That's an answer not a comment

Comment: @Dave, For some reason, I was considering the possibility of using two different iterator types, but looking back, that seems pretty unlikely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++11, you say `auto it1 = std::next(it, 1);`.

Prior to that, you have to say something like:

```
std::map<K, T>::iterator it1 = it;
std::advance(it1, 1);
```

Don't forget to `#include <iterator>`.

Comment: Note you can just say `std::next(it)`, the second param is defaulted to 1